# Is there a way to pick *.HEIC files from an ios device in Flutter using Image_Picker or similar plugins from pub.dev?

Tags: ios, flutter, path, imagepicker, heic

i'm developing an App where I can upload images/photos from my phone photo gallery (ios device) to firebase.
Since I want to upload the images/photos in original format (e.g. *.HEIC for pictures taken by an iPhone) I need a plugin which allows me to do that.

Following plugin's I've tried so far:

- [wechat_assets_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/wechat_assets_picker): this one does what I want to have and returns me a temporary path which contains the the picked image in it's original format (e.g.:     `/anyPath/tmp/IMG_0024.HEIC`). But since I don't really like the UI of wechat_assets_picker, I would like to have sth. else. Maybe more native looking
- [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker): returns a path where the picture is converterd to *.jpeg (e.g.: `/anyPath/image_picker_randomNumber.jpg`). This is not what I want!
- [images_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/images_picker): same as image_picker... converts the image to *.jpg
- [image_pickers](https://pub.dev/packages/image_pickers): similar to wechat_assets_picker but it does what I want. But I don't like the UI either
- [likk_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/likk_picker): same - not what I'm looking for
- [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker): same - returns *.jpg

I'm getting tired trying all the plugins.
Is there anyone who can support? Maybe any other way how to pick an image from my gallery in it's original format and quality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that other plugins usually compress HEICs when picking, I would suggest you consider the below solutions:

- wechat_assets_picker allows you to build your widgets using delegations. By override build delegates, you can customize each part or the whole part of the interface.
- wechat_assets_picker depends on the underlying plugin [photo_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager) which allows you to build your widgets from the bottom on your own.